# Efficient way to handle identical functions but with different operators in C

Tags: c, operators

Lets say in C I have 2 methods that are completly identical but 1 adds the value and the other substracts it:

```
void decreaseValue(handle* myData, uint8_t amount)
{
    /* Stuff going on */
    myData->someAttribute -= amount;
    /* Stuff going on */
}

void increaseValue(handle* myData, uint8_t amount)
{
    /* Stuff going on */
    myData->someAttribute += amount;
    /* Stuff going on */
}
```

Except for the operators, both functions are completly identical resulting in quite a few lines of duplicated code that is not trivial.

Is there a safe, portable, non-ugly way of handling this or I'm stuck with ctrl+c ctrl+v?

**Possiblity of a switch-case:**

```
typedef enum
{
    ADD,
    SUBSTRACT
}operator;

void modifyValue(handle* myData, uint8_t amount, operator op)
{
    /* Stuff going on */
    switch(op){
    case ADD: 
        myData->someAttribute += amount;
        break;
    case SUBSTRACT:
        myData->someAttribute -= amount;
        break;
    /* Stuff going on */
}
```

It works but doesn't feel any better.

Comment: `switch - case` statement ? This requires the function to take an additional parameter.

Comment: Because subtracting is the same as adding negative value, i would look into passing negative values this way you keep one method

Comment: @meda You should make it into an answer I think you're right. I can just merge the 2 functions into modify(handle* myData, int8_t amount) and the user will pass negative values instead of having to mock polymorphism or decide which function to call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
static inline void changeValue(handle* myData, int amount)
{
    /* Stuff going on */
    myData->someAttribute += amount;
    /* Stuff going on */
}

void increaseValue(handle* myData, uint8_t amount)
{
    changeValue(myData, (int)amount);
}

void decreaseValue(handle* myData, uint8_t amount)
{
    changeValue(myData, -(int)amount);
}
```

Comment: You made me realise there is absolutely no reason I'm passing an unsigned value with 2 different functions in the first place. I see how your solution is tailored so I don't have to change my interface. I think I fell into the XY problem with my question.

Comment: @Asics: No problem :) ... What's the *XY Problem* though?

Comment: Its when you have problem X and partial solution Y and instead of finding a better way to solve X you try to refactor Y into a more elegant solution while it doesn't answer well the core problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Using preprocessor:

```
#define modifyValue(name, operator)                  \
    void name##Value(handle* myData, uint8_t amount) \
    {                                                \
        /* Stuff going on */                         \
        myData->someAttribute operator= amount;      \
        /* Stuff going on */                         \
    }

modifyValue(increase, +)
modifyValue(decrease, -)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about an `enum`?

```
typedef enum
{
    SUBTRACT,
    ADD,
    ...
} enumOperator;

void modifyValue(handle* myData, uint8_t amount, enumOperator operator)
{
    switch(operator)
    {
        case SUBTRACT:
            myData->someAttribute -= amount;
            break;
        case ADD:
            myData->someAttribute += amount;
            break;
        case ...:
            ...;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two functions

```
void addAmount(handle* myData, uint8_t amount)
{
    myData->someAttribute += amount;    
}

void subtractAmount(handle* myData, uint8_t amount)
{
    myData->someAttribute -= amount;    
}
```

Create a genericFunction that can accept one of the above functions as an argument.

```
void genericFunction(handle* myData, uint8_t amount,
                     void (*fun)(handle*, uint8_t))
{
    /* Stuff going on */

    /* Call the function */
    fun(myData, amount);

    /* Stuff going on */
}
```

Call `genericFunction` with `addAmount` or `subtractAmount`

```
genericFunction(mData, amount, addAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your method is small enough better don't call any unnecessary function. Use if-else or switch.

Answer (score -1):

```
void doStuff(handle* myData, uint8_t amount, void (*func)(handle*, uint8_t))
{
    /* Stuff going on */
    func(myData, amount);
    /* Stuff going on */
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
void decrease(handle* myData, uint8_t amount) { myData->someAttribute -= amount; }
void increase(handle* myData, uint8_t amount) { myData->someAttribute += amount; }

void decreaseValue(handle* myData, uint8_t amount)
{
    doStuff(myData, amount, decrease);
}
void increaseValue(handle* myData, uint8_t amount)
{
    doStuff(myData, amount, increase);
}
```

Basically you are using the equivalent of delegates (or lambdas) in C. `doStuff` does the actual things that would be duplicated.